# Asp.net Forms authentication with Auth0 login

Tags: asp.net, webforms, forms-authentication, auth0

I am having a classic ASP.net web application with windows authentication.

Now the requirement is to login using Auth0 with Forms authentication. I am getting an issue where Owincontect challenge is getting called continuously as a loop. Below is my code,

Enabled Forms authentication in IIS.

web config as,

```
    <add key="oidc:Authority" value=" https://url/authorize" />
    <add key="oidc:ClientId" value="abcd" />
    <add key="oidc:ClientSecret" value="abcd" />
    <add key="oidc:RedirectUrl" value="http://localhost:8080/callback" />
```

startup class,

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);
        }



public partial class Startup
    {
        public static string OidcAuthority = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["oidc:Authority"];
        public static string OidcRedirectUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["oidc:RedirectUrl"];
        public static string OidcClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["oidc:ClientId"];
        public static string OidcClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["oidc:ClientSecret"];



        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());



            var oidcOptions = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Authority = OidcAuthority,
                ClientId = OidcClientId,
                RequireHttpsMetadata = false, //when deploy it should be http comment this 
                ClientSecret = OidcClientSecret,
                GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = OidcRedirectUrl,
                RedirectUri = OidcRedirectUrl,
                ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code,
                Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenId,

            };



            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(oidcOptions);
        }
    }
```

And in all the pages , I have added helper class object which checks the authenticated conditions including global.asax file,

```
Helpers.AuthHelper help = new Helpers.AuthHelper();
            help.IsAuthenticated();




public  void IsAuthenticated()
        {
            
            if (!HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge();
            }

            var claims = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Claims;

        }
```

The issue is , it is not redirecting to the page expected and also to the auth0 login page, It got stuck in login page which I created.

[image]

Gets the above error page, As I have no code added inside login.aspx page. Little stuck in the continuity here. I am not clear if I am in right direction or any change is required for enabling forms authentication with Auth0 as I should not add authentication mode inside web config.

Regards
Sangeetha

Comment: Please refere [this](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/aspnet-owin)